# PrintWriter issues

Tags: java, outputstream

I am writing a program, designed to ping an online database, and write a log of the status to a .txt.

Whenever i run the program and open the .txt, the timestamp tells me that it has just been changed, but it is blank.

```
public static void printToFile(String text) {
    String fileName = "log.txt";
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        System.out.println("Printing to txt");
        outputStream.println("Debug");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file " + fileName);
        outputStream.close();
    }
}

public static void pingDatabase(Connection conn) throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
    Date timeStamp = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    do {
        if (conn.isValid(10000)) {
            System.out.println("Printtofile called");
            printToFile("Database is Online");
        } else {
            printToFile("Database is Offline");
        }
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } while (true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is log you might need to append the content instead of writing every time and need to flush the content to log file after writing.

```
public static void printToFile(String text)  {
        String fileName = "log.txt";
        PrintWriter outputStream=null;
        try {
             outputStream =new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName,true));
            System.out.println("Printing to txt");
            outputStream.append(text+"\n");
            outputStream.flush();//flushing to file
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " + fileName);

        }
        finally{
              outputStream.close();
        }
        }
```

*new FileWriter(fileName,true)* FileWriter is subclass of OutPutStreamWriter and `true` for opening in append mode

Comment: Please explain why closing the stream is necessary in the `catch` block but not at any other time, and why an `IOException` can only be due to a problem opening the file and nothing else.

Comment: @EJP just done with one part so i will work on that, and also looking for that and u downvoted, u also would have been left comment

Comment: You don't have any information about who downvoted your answer. Your edit assumes no exception was thrown.

Comment: I know and its really nightmare who downvote without comment, at the time when just answered like one mnt before

Comment: @EJP FileNotFoundException only not enough as PrintWriter required IOException to catch

Comment: That's *my* point. Not all exceptions here are due to not being able to open the file. I already said that.

Comment: Thanks, i got the problem fixed, how can i limit the .txt to only contain the 10 most recent loggings?

Comment: multiple ways to get around , in one run you can take var and increase after each write and when it reach ten #do what u want

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing, or therefore flushing, your `PrintWriter` unless there is an exception.

You also need to open your output file in append mode, given your  current code, but it would make more sense to keep it open. The overhead of opening and closing a file per message is enormous.

Comment: @Roushan Same answer as what? The only same answer I can see here is one that relies on information provided by me.

Comment: which info provoided by u? i dont get such

Comment: @Roushan That's what I said, in my answer, and in my comment on your answer, and it also appears to be what yiu are claiming proprietary rights over, which you don't have. If you have some other point to make, please make it. Presently this is just noise.